# Unable to bind object properties in an angular template

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I am unable to bind the object in the angular template. My variable "filter" has my required object. It is of type Current and i want to show the properties of Current interface in a table. However, when i try to bind the object in the template, i get a drop down as  'module.exports'. I am new to angular and dont understand what it means. In most of the example codes that i saw, i should be directly able to bind Object.Property to my html element. Pls help.

html:

```
            <tr>
                <td>{{filter}}</td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

component:

```
 weatherData : Weather | undefined;
    filter!:Current;
    sub!: Subscription;
    getData(){
        this.sub = this.weatherService.getCurrentData(this.inputText).subscribe(x=>this.Observer(x));
    }
    Observer(x: Weather): void {
        this.weatherData = x;
        console.log(this.weatherData.current);
        this.filter = this.weatherData.current;
    }
```

Current interface[image]:

```
export interface Current{
    time: string,
    temperature: number,
}
```

Comment: Update: Instead of trying to bind in the templateUrl, i am able to bind the object to my table inside an inline template of the component. I wonder if I am missing to explicitly import/export the Current class somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

You defined the interface as `Current` but calling it `CurrentClass`.

Try changing it to:
`filter!:Current;`

Comment: I tried doing that but it isn’t working too☹️

Comment: Try moving: ```this.weatherData = x; this.filter = this.weatherData.current;``` into the getData() function

Comment: nope..that does not work. I am getting the proper data in my "filter" property. But i cannot bind it in the template. If i create a property in my ts file like time = filter.time and then bind the template to time, it is displaying the value in the template. But i am unable to bind to filter.time in my <tr>